# Objective C - Iphone - Is it possible to edit/delete the image from gallery?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I am working on a app which requires image edit/delete from the phone image gallery. Is it really possible to do that?

I googled and ended up like - No.

Can somebody help me to figureout this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do that.
You can choose a photo from gallery edit it and save as a new image to iOS photo-gallery. Currently there is no permission for edit and delete.

Comment: OK. Then is it possible to move from Phone Gallery to app album? I need to move the photo from Gallery? Is there any alternate?

Comment: @KiranVarthi: No, you can only do something with the copy of that image. Another way you can store the photos in your applications Document directory, and pick and edit/delete from there

Comment: Tx. One more doubt...  Is it possible to overcome this if we use binary code reading/writing mechanism ?

Comment: @KiranVarthi: You can do these on jail-broken devices. In normal devices. It won't work